# In what court would one sue another for assault as trespass to person?

Tags: england-and-wales, tort, assault

In England and Wales, what court can one use to sue another for assaulting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Civil justice in England and Wales is mainly dealt with in the county
> courts and, in the case of more substantial or complex cases, the High
> Court. The jurisdiction covers a very wide range – from quite small or
> simple claims, for example damaged goods or recovery of debt, to large
> claims between multi-national companies.

https://www.judiciary.uk/about-the-judiciary/the-justice-system/jurisdictions/civil-jurisdiction/

Comment: Can trespass to person for less than £10K be pursued under the small claims track?

Comment: @JosephP. 'You' can't apply for the small claims track for personal injury claims.

Comment: What do you mean by "'you'"

Comment: @JosephP. a person, a plaintiff "can't apply for the small claims track for personal injury claim."